# Time resolution of IFFT in python

Tags: python, fft

I'm trying to process the S11 parameter directly measured by VNA in time domain by using IFFT transform but I'm a little bit confused about the calculation of the time duration or time window T (the total length of the data on the time axis) and the corresponding time resolution 'ts'.

For example, if my S11 data is within the bandwidth between 5-10GHz with N = 101 points. My calculations of time window T and ts are:

Considering the Hermitian Procssing and zero-padding, the total number of samples are L = 403

```
ΔF = f_max - f_min = 10GHz - 5GHz
fs = ΔF/(N)
ts = 1/(L * fs)
T = (L-1) * ts
```

But in some literature I saw different calculation as `ts = 1/(ΔF)`  or `ts = 1/(N * fs)`, which in Python as:

```py
freq = np.linspace(ini_f, fin_f, n_freqs)
fs = freq_vector[1] - freq_vector[0]
ts = 1 / (n_freqs * fs)
T = np.linspace(0, n_freqs * ts, n_freqs)
```

I wonder which one is right?

I use my calculation for the processing in Matlab which seems alright so is it because the difference of `ifft` in Python and Matlab? Do we need to consider the Hermitian Procssing and zero-padding in when dealing with the scenario using Python?

Comment: I don't understand what you expect to learn from this.  Are you trying to recreate the signal that the VNA sent out?

Comment: I don't think this is a question about programming. You might be better off asking this on a forum about physics or maybe signal processing. The `ifft()` function in MATLAB does the same thing as `np.fft.ifft()` in Python, they even have the same normalization (which is the thing that could be different in different implementations of the FFT).

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to transform the complex frequency domain S-parameter into time domain and then doing further processing like DAS or so

Comment: Are you saying that you have working code in Matlab but the Python code does not work? If so, you have to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in both languages

Comment: Both code works well but I don't understand why where're different calculations. Like Cris says it seems more like a signal processing question.